# 'On behalf of' usage

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I have read many sentences making use of 'on behalf of' meaning 'as a representative of'. I know behalf is a noun, so when we could use 'on the behalf of' in a sentence? I consulted many websites, but none of them used 'the' article before 'behalf'. Is it wrong to use 'the' before this noun? Why? If i do use it, what would it mean?

Comment: The idiomatic expression has always been without the definite article, but "on the behalf of" is not incorrect, it has been there all along and is still found in some writing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on behalf of ,in addition to, on account of etc. are prepostional phrases and they are idiomatic. So we can not use any article before the nouns.

We say:

1.I spoke on behalf of my Principal but not **on the behalf of**

2.Tomorrow is a holiday on account of Diwali.

There are certain phrases such as on fire , send word which do not take any article.

Comment: Thank you for the answer:)

Comment: okay. And in the sentence if i say "There was a delay of 2 hours" Or "There was the delay of 2 hours." What do these two sentences imply? (usage of the)

Comment: how to accept the answer?

Comment: @user36956.In my answer you will find a right mark  and you have to press it. If you want to upvote it you have to press on the top.

Comment: @user36956.Press below the triangle and press on the top triangle

Comment: @user36956.Now you can upvote by pressing the triangle at the top

Comment: Yet, i 'm under 15 rep. Whenever, i reach 15, i 'll do it.:)

Comment: JVL, did you mean 'Principal' ?